# Best practice to use nested templates in marionette.js

Tags: javascript, nested, marionette

I've been looking into single page apps and started with Marionette.js today.
I found that the overall structure of the application is very effective (modules, events, etc) i can not get into idea how to use templates(views) to get most of them when using complicated data structures. i am used to handlebars-like templates that can do some additional logic and nesting.

What are the best practices to display nested templates?

Consider this not so complex data structure with nested data:

```
[{name:"John", addresses:
  [
    {street:"John Street",city:"New York, NY"},
    {street:"John Street",city:"Madrid, PA"}
  ],
  notes: [{note:"note1"},{note:"note2"}]
  },
  {name:"Alex", addresses:
  [
    {street:"Alex Street",city:"New York, NY"},
    {street:"Alex Street",city:"Madrid, PA"}
  ],
  notes: {}}
]
```

How to effectively render first-level array as table rows and inner arrays (like "addresses" and "notes") into individual columns in the row (in form of another table, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Marionette provides for Collection and CompositeViews to render collection of objects.
Tables can be effectively rendered by using CompositeView
See docs for [CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md) - it has a example of how to render table using compositeview.

For rendering complex, nested structures, it's best to Handlebars as it allows one to reference nested fields example : `{{x.y}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CollectionView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md), your array will be passed to the view as its `collection`, you could then loop through the `addresses` for each row to display those.

I would not create a view for each element of the `addresses` array since there's not need to manage them by themselves, they will be showed when the main view is showed (right?).

So you could have something like this

```
NoUsers = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#no-users-template"
});
```

which will be used when the passed `collection` is empty

```
User = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({});
```

which will define how a single user (your top level array element) will be rendered, you coudl use Handlebars to do the `addresses` looping, something like

```
<div>
  {{ #each addresses }}
  <span>{{ street }} - {{ city }}</span>
  {{/each}}
</div>

Users = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView({
  itemView: User,
  emptyView: NoUsers
});
```

which will define how it all plays together, for a detailed example see [this example app](https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail/blob/master/public/javascripts/bbclonemail/contacts/contactsapp.js) made from DErick Bailey, the creator of Marionette.

Comment: In this case User(which is Itemview) should implement additional logic (like you said looping through addresses and notes, putting them in temporary variable and then rendering it?). Should I do it somewhere like initialize or in beforeRender?

Comment: Usually you do that kind of stuff in the template, using handlebars' each to do the looping, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for extended reply, but these handlebar templates would not work out of the box or would they? should i also redefine "template" method in itemview to point it to handlebars?

Comment: You should import handlebars in your project. There are detailed guides around on how to do this, it will not be difficult.

Comment: okay, it's compicated to add handlebars to marionette due to conflicts with versions. at the moment i decided to use a monster like this:  onBeforeRender: function(){
    this.model.set('tmp_field',this.model.has('addresses')?
              _.reduce(this.model.get('addresses'), function(result, value){return result+"Address: "+value.street+" " +value.city+ "<br>";},""):"No address");
  }

Comment: it's possible to use _.template in the anonymous function also, but anyway all this looks more like a hack than actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using underscore, you can do

```
<%= Marionette.Renderer.render('#your-template', {
    your: data,
    goes: here
}) %>
```

or a better example would be

```
<% _.each(someArrayOnModel, function(item) { %>
    <%= Marionette.Renderer.render('#templateForItem', item) %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: sounds good, but breaks the concept of MVC a bit. also "your data goes here" should be something like this.model.addresses in this case?

Comment: <updated example>  which is a good approach if you are using underscore and dont want the overhead of a CollectionView

Comment: one of the problems here is that itemview(if called from CompositeView) gets a "model", not a "collection" and _.each would not work properly. i tried _.each(this.model) but it does not give any result.

Comment: correct, if you are doing this then you probably aren't using a compositeview or collectionview.  those things are cool (in which case you'd use marionette itemviews to deal with the subtemplates) but for many readonly scenarios, they bring unnecessary overhead so i just use an itemview (giving it the collection as the model) and loop as shown here